# How to handle exceptions in a multi-layered ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, exception, multi-layer

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application with **UI**, **Service layer** and **Repository layer**.

Some of the methods in my **Service Layer** communicates with a Web Service, therefore I would like to wrap all the calls to the Web Methods in a `Try-Catch-Finally` construct.

Suppose I have the following methods in my **Service Layer**:

```
public RegistrationDetails GetRegistrationDetails(int userId)

public bool RegisterUser(UserData myUserData)
```

Where `RegistrationDetails` and `myUserData` are object types (classes).

My concern is the following: if I create a `Try-Catch-Finally` to wrap the call to the Web Service within the implementation of the methods listed above, in case there is an exception how can I return the message string if the return types are `RegistrationDetails` and `bool`?

I was thinking about adding a property to every return object but I do not know if that is a good solution. For instance instead of using `bool`:

```
public class RegisterResponse
{
   public bool isRegistered { get; set; }
   public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
}

public RegisterResponse RegisterUser(UserData myUserData)
```

And then check if ExceptionMessage is `null` or `String.Empty`. Is it a good approach? Thanks

Comment: I usually let the exception bubble up to a form and handle it there. When you catch a specific exception at a lower level, it's possible that you're missing the real cause of the error somewhere in-between. At the lower levels, I just throw them...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason why I want to catch all the exceptions is to avoid the user to see the typical ASP.NET error page. I would like instead to handle them and display to the user (through the UI) the best set of information in order ease the problem-solving process.

Answer (score 0):

1) As mentioned by IrishChieftain, bubbling the exception down to the forms is good, you will be able to respond to the exception better

2) You can also have a reference parameter as array which stores exception messages generated from the method

```
public bool RegisterUser(UserData myUserData, optional ref ArrayList<string> errors)
{
  if(error)
    errors.Add("This error occured")
}
```

3) For Instance Object, you could have an Instance variable of ArrayList for errors and have that returned in a property

```
public class MyClass
{
   private ArrayList<string> errors = new ArrayList<string>

   public ArrayList<string> ExceptionMessages()
   {
      get 
      {
          return errors;
      }
   }

  public RegistrationDetails GetRegistrationDetails(int userId) { }
}

//Used like this:
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.GetRegistrationDetails();

if(c.ExceptionMessages > 0)
{
    //output errors
}
```

But I would prefer the first approach - for flexibility like output formatting

Answer (score 0):

Passing raw exceptions on to your client (web forms layer) from a service could be risky. If it's a database exception, it might expose details of your database. A malicious user might call your service layer methods from their own application.

You can expect two types of exceptions on the client level:

1. Communication Exception (problems connecting to the service)
2. Server-side error (database problem, username not unique, password invalid... other business rule exceptions)

The first type should be caught in try-catch-finally in your web forms layer, but the second kind should be caught in the service layer, logged, then wrapped up in the `RegisterResponse` object, as you suggest. But, instead of sending Exception.Message, you might consider using an enum of expected errors (with a ServerError member to cover anything else.) You could also add an EventId to the response and log entry so that you can investigate errors.

```
public enum RegisterResponseError { NoError = 0, SystemError = 1, 
    UserNameNotUnique, PasswordInvalid, etc.  }

public class RegisterResponse
{
   public bool isRegistered { get; set; }
   public RegisterResponseError ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your client code,

```
if(myRegisterResponse.ErrorCode == RegisterResponseError.NoError)
   // everything was fine
else
  // show a suitable error message for ErrorCode and display EventId (if logging)
```

You could return an error string from your service, but it's probably better to manage any content in your web forms layer, in case you need to localize the content or use a CMS later on.